# Measuring thermal conductivity

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetic-theory

Suppose we have a long, cylindrical, wire of radius $a$ and a resistance $R$ (per unit length), which is laid out along the axis of a hollow cylinder of radius $b$, which is kept at a fixed temperature $T_0$, filled with gas whom thermal conductivity is $\kappa$.

In that scenario, how does one estimate $\kappa$. Seems like, if we allow current to flow through the wire, we could simply calculate the temperature difference between the wire and the recipient at a steady state. But I really do not know how.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You will have to do your experiment in zero gravity, otherwise heat transport by convection will dominate over thermal conductivity in a fluid.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious place to start is the heat equation:

\begin{equation}\Phi=-\kappa\nabla T=-\kappa\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial r}\hat r \end{equation}
Supposing a 1-d flow. Since current flows through the wire, it dissipates energy in the form $I²R$, per unit lenght. Understanding flux as flow rate per unit area:
\begin{equation}\frac{I²R}{A}=-\kappa\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial r} \end{equation}
Now we take an gaussian cylinder of lenght $l$ and radius $r$, so that:
\begin{equation}\frac{I²R}{2\pi rl}=-\kappa\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}\implies\int_{T}^{T_0}dT=-\frac{I²R}{2\pi l\kappa}\int_{a}^{b}\frac{dr}{r}\implies T=T_0+\frac{I²\mathcal{R}}{2\pi\kappa}\ln\frac{b}{a}\end{equation}

Giving the desired answer.